# Get all the users information in system and backup it in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am an Admin user and want to run program in C# to get all the user information of the current computer irrespective of domain and make backup of them (if possible with passwords), so if computer reformats, i can restore all user information using C#.

Thanks for the answers.

Ashutosh

Comment: You cannot backup Windows passwords (well, at least not in plain text) - thank God! For the other stuff simply saying "all the user information" is way to vague. Consider doing a "simple" but complete backup of the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.

I finally found some help here:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/iersoy/getting-all-users-in-a-computer/

Thanks

Ashutosh

Answer (score 2):

The link following will tell you how to do this with gui.
Active Directory Backup and Restore
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727062.aspx

If you want to use C# to operate these steps, follow the following steps:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = " WBADMIN.exe";
p.Start();

p.StandardInput.WriteLine(“START SYSTEMSTATEBACKUP -backupTarget:F:”);
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");

// Display the response message
System.Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [NirSoft](http://nirsoft.net), it have a lot of utilities could be useful to you, almost utilities have -export command line argument that make you able to export it to external file